# Left to right scrolling in app based on flutter

Tags: flutter

As we have list view kind of stuff for up to down scrolling. Is there anything for the left to right scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scrollDirection` property on `ListView` to set the axis.

For horizontal scrolling, you can use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`.

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[...]
);
```